# Getting error while installing Managed Package in MS CRM Online

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am getting following error while installing my Managed Package in my customer's system. First of all I don't know following are error or not. I have just identified that they are unprocessed. I have also added screenshot. Please guide me.

1- Unprocessed: Client Extensions

2- Unprocessed: Workflow Activation - LicenseProcess

3- Unprocessed: Plugin Assembly - SamplePlugins, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829f574d80e89132

4- Unprocessed: Plugin Assembly - StockLicensePlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5dae860a58237d7f

5- Unprocessed: SDK Message Processing Step: Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.StockPluginUpdate: Update of salesorder

6- Unprocessed: Publish StringMaps

7- Unprocessed: Root Components Insertion

8- Unprocessed: Dependencies Calculation

I don't know about Error 1, 6, 7, 8. 
Error 2, 3, 4, 5 is about Plugin Assembly that I have added for License and Stock update purpose.

Can anybody please suggest me appropriate way? I am damn stuck

Here is Log Screenshot:
[image]